# Facebook integration using python library

Tags: python, facebook

I created a simple web app using django and was wondering if there is any python library out there that could help me integrate my app with facebook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple search for "facebook" on PyPI

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=facebook&submit=search

gives two django related modules with the first two hits.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-facebook/2.0.16

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-la-facebook/0.1.0

Apart from that there is always the official Facebook SDK (on PyPI) that you will find on Github (also carrying several forks of the SDK):

google "facebook sdk python"

Please some more research next time....

Comment: Please, tone it down a bit. You come off as abrasive.

Comment: Although you were right about the answer, you reminded me of this.http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2F89N6--3qg/TWS2n-y6RRI/AAAAAAAAAHM/vl7nTPWY08U/s1600/toughguysyndrom.jpg.